# Wrong opacity transition behaviour in Chrome when loading CSS from file?

Tags: css

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here or whether this indeed is a Chrome rendering bug.

Here is my very small example:

```css
.hover-test span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}
.hover-test:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST opacity</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<button class="hover-test">hover me<span>hidden</span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

It works in all browsers I checked like expected.

It does work in Chrome as well, when I put the CSS in a style tag directly in the HTML file.

It does **NOT** work in Chrome (91.0.4472.101), when I put the CSS in a separate file and include it with a link tag.

With "not working" I mean, that on page load the span is shown and then faded out, without the mouse cursor being near the button.

Is this a Chrome bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

How can I achieve the desired behaviour in Chrome, which is: span is hidden on page load and only shown/hidden on hover?

Comment: This seems weird. In what order do you include the css rules?

Comment: Actually no order, just one styles.css file with the CSS from my question

Comment: This should not be happening. If I were to guess, I'd say you have something else conflicting with the opacity, before the `.hover-span test` rule, causing your css to load the item with opacity of 1 and then animate it to opacity 0. A general `span` rule perhaps or even a `body` rule. I'd search for all the opacity rules and go from there

Comment: I created two files with exactly the code from above. No other code involved. Uploaded it here: https://helhum.io/opacity-test.html 
On a webserver with caching I can only reproduce it, when the CSS file des not come cache, thus it only happens on a forced reload of the page (shift + reload button). Still weird though IMHO

Comment: This is a timing issue, the html loads well before the css. That's why you only see this on the first load. If you want to "fix" this, you can hide the body or the html inside the html and have the css file show it. You can use `display`,`visibility`, `opacity` or whatever

Comment: Actually it is a chrome bug, which was fixed 11 days ago: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332189 But nevertheless I will apply a workaround similar to the one you suggested for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a Chrome bug,as written here: https://www.hawkbydesign.com/weird-google-chrome-css-transition-on-load-bug/

> Well, after making some further updates and refreshing the page, I noticed that the transition was firing on page load. What I mean by this is instead of being hidden on page load, as they should be, the elements were visible and would transition to their hidden state.

this is exactly the problem reported.

More:

> The bug happens whenever you don’t have any script tags on the page, apparently. For whatever reason, this causes css transitions to trigger upon page load. While I was also digging, it appears that this happens sometimes with the form tag as well. What a weird bug!

> The solution is to include a script tag in your page. Whenever I found the solution, they said to include a space in the script tag, but I found that it works fine even without the space.

I actually added jQuery on the page using the CDN link and the bug seems gone.

Comment: Actually on my production page I had a JS include, but used defer
<script defer="defer" src="main.js"></script>
Removing the defer from this script tag (before closing body tag) solved the issue as well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be bumping up against a timing problem.

Try this code with your styles file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST opacity</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

   </style>
   </head>
<body>
<script>
function insert() {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<button class="hover-test">hover me<span>hidden</span></button>';
}
window.onload = insert;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This waits for loading before putting the button in the document and on Chrome (and Edge) on Windows10 at least all is well.

Chrome/Edge seem to differ from say Firefox in whether loading is synchronous or not - or maybe it's just a lot faster writing the document.

Comment: Obviously this cannot be a solution for a production website :)

Comment: Agreed, but it's an explanation.